# Uniformly Continuous secondary definition.

Tags: real-analysis

I've been given the following definition for uniformly continuous,

$f:A \to \mathbb{R}, \ f$ is uniformly continuous on A, $\forall \ \epsilon >0 \ \exists \ \delta>0$ such that $\forall \ a \in \mathbb{R}, |x-a|< \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$.

My question to this is, how would one extend this to have it be expressed as sequences. Essentially how to state f is uniformly continuous using a sequential definition?

Thanks

Edit: I took a stab at this and got the following,
Suppose $f$ is continuous and $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$, we say that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ if and only if for every sequence $\{ x_n \}, \{ y_n \}$ in $A$, $|x_n-y_n| \to 0 \implies|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \to 0$.

Would this be a good form of the sequential definition?

Comment: Just a brief comment in passing (about to get off-line for the day) -- For me, the 2nd highest hit (Wikipedia article on uniform continuity was the highest) of a google search for ["uniformly continuous" + definition + sequences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uniformly+continuous%22+definition+sequences) was [these notes](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/lecture_notes/uniform.pdf) (see p. 3).

Comment: Are you just looking for an answer like "yes-- this is fine"?  See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1090756/148510

Comment: Thanks for the feedback to both of you. I just wanted to make sure that my understanding of the transition was up to par. I normally try to avoid using google too much to help develop my real analysis skills and prefer the feedback here as it's more of a face-to-face approach.