# Constructive Proofs in Elementary Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In considering the theorem cited here [uniform continuity and equivalent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090756/uniform-continuity-and-equivalent-sequences) , which states that where $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function, the following two conditions are equivalent:

(a) $f$ is uniformly continuous

(b) If $(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(y_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are equivalent sequences of real numbers, then $(f(x_{n}))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(f(y_{n}))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are also equivalent sequences of real numbers.

I was curious as to whether a direct proof could be offered for $(b) \rightarrow (a)$, and if not, how one would go about proving this. (I don’t have  a sufficiently thorough background in intuitionistic logic to offer the latter kind of proof so wanted to solicit answers from whose who do). Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hm... I don't think I agree with the vote to close this question. It seems like it has plenty of context to me. In general "what happens intuitionistically" is a fair question, and newcomers to the field will likely have trouble answering such questions themselves. Regardless, here's a comment since I can't leave an answer: No, there is no constructive proof that $(b) \to (a)$. Condition $(b)$ is called "uniform sequential continuity" and constructively it's known to be weaker than uniform continuity (though, as your linked question shows, they are equivalent classically).

Comment: In fact, $(b) \to (a)$ is equivalent to the statement "every countable pseudobounded sequence of naturals is bounded", which is known to be unprovable intuitionistically. See Theorem 9 in Bridges, Ishihara, Schuster, and Vita's [_Strong Continuity Implies Uniform Sequential Continuity_](https://www.math.canterbury.ac.nz/research/ucdms2001n2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for replying. The information you've provided there (despite not leaving a comment), is nevertheless very insightful! :)